# Issues at Apache.org does not cantain Apache Cordova for create issue tab

Tags: apache, cordova, jira, apache-cordova

I want to raise issue at
https://issues.apache.org/jira

For Apache Cordova based project

[image: Screenshot for Create issue window]

In above image there is no Apache Cordova Project

Does any one help me on that ??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Cordova has moved from JIRA to GitHub issues, so you now have to report it on the affected component/platform/plugin.

More information [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova#filing-a-bug)